# MySQL Update column with case on joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, update, case

I have 2 tables and I want to update table 1 using a case check on table 2:

```
update 
cms.Clients c #c_id unique
join 
cms.ClientDomains d #c_id not unique
on c.c_id = d.c_id
set c.country =
    case 
        when d.domain_id=2 then 'MEX' 
        when d.domain_id=1 then 'USA' 
    end
where c.c_id in (113113)
```

This update changes for domain id 2 the country to 'USA'.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can we have table structures (SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G for your tables, a few lines of sample data (INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES(...) and your desired result and the logic you used to get it.

Comment: I guess it happens because there is more than one record in `d` with the same `c_id` but different `domain_id` (2 rows in d with c_id =113113, one with domain_id =1 , another with domain_id=2) .

Comment: OK, my bad, I guess because d.c_id is not unique on domains table, the query scans the the clients table only once and update it. the select on the join will show 2 rows for this client but he can have only one country - per the one scan in the update.